# Как настроить правильно кодировку для MySQL?

Tags: mysqli, php, кодировка, mysql

Вот... Изучаю PHP. Дошла до соединения с БД.
И тут такая проблема.

В файле *.php прописываю соединение с БД.
Затем прописываю запросы, вывожу результаты на экран.

Все работает. Ошибок не выдает. НО! Проблема:
русский текст не распознается. Выводит знаки ???
При этом английские буквы нормально выводит.

Так понимаю, что проблемы с кодировкой.
Кодировку меняла и в самом php-файле, и в БД.
На windows-1251 и на utf-8 и utf8_general_ci.

Видимо я пишу по старой версии PHP, и для PHP 5.х
этот метод не подходит. Но я учусь по книжке, там так
написано...

В сети [нашла решение моей проблемы.][1]

Но уже который час читаю, глаза уже красные,
не могу понять, что делаю не так. Если писать на основе
примеров, которые там написаны, то у меня сразу три ошибки
выдает. Вообще, как это использовать правильно?
Ничего не помогает. Что нужно сделать?
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Код, который писала по книге такой:

```
<?php
   $db=mysql_connect("localhost","one","12345");
   mysql_select_db("firstbd",$db);

   $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firma",$db);
   $myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result);

   echo $myrow["id_firma"];
   echo " - ".$myrow["name"];
   echo " ".$myrow["surname"];
   echo " - ".$myrow["doljnost"];
?>
```

Только просьба ко всем большая. Давайте не будем тут разговаривать на тему, зачем девушке программирование. Уже общались по этому вопросу. Изучаю - значит надо. Спасибо за понимание:)
[1]: https://www.php.net/mysqli_set_charset

Comment: Так раз вы нашли решение, но оно выдает 3 ошибки, то может быть стоит спросить про эти ошибки?

На вскидку - ссылка у вас на mysqli, а в коде - mysql, может быть потому ошибки и были? Лучше делайте все через mysqli, все-таки mysql устаревший

Приведите текст ошибки, тогда поможем.

И еще, на всякий случай - а при отображении страницы какую кодировку отправляете?

Comment: @BOPOH, да, я стала делать с помощью mysqli, но проблема осталась той же. Ниже привела код с описанием проблемы на настоящий момент.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Подключение
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("db");
mysql_set_charset("utf8")
```

либо если используется mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "bd");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")

// Дальше работа с базой
```

При создании базы так же использовать кодировку utf8_general_ci, либо перевести в нее текущию. Так же ставте заголовок charset=UTF-8 и переводите кодировку самого файла (где пишите код и вообще все файлы) в кодировку UTF-8.

После понимания синтаксиса советую все делать в mysqli(нежели mysql) т.к. удобнее, есть поддержка, ну и ООП естественно, но это уже потом узнаете) Удачи.

Comment: @hase, да, изначально БД в utf8_general_ci делаю.

Comment: Дописал, т.к. не только база должна быть в UTF-8 )

Comment: @hase Спасибо! Буду применять.

Answer (score 3):

Возьмите за правило писать в кодировке `UTF-8`.

- Сохраните свои скрипты в кодировке
     `utf-8`
- Отдавайте заголовки, что вы    скрипт
     генерит контент в `utf-8`
- После  успешного соединения с БД выполните  сразу же такой запрос: `'SET NAMES utf8';`

использую перечисленные выше принципы, и проблемы с кодировкой нет.

Comment: mysqli_set_charset:

>>Это предпочтительный способ задания набора символов. Использование для этих целей функции mysqli_query() (например SET NAMES utf8) не рекомендуется.

Comment: @BOPOH, автор использует устаревший api.

Comment: Я заметил и написал об этом в комменте. Если не менять на mysqli, то есть [mysql_set_charset](http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

Хотя не менять не вижу причин - ведь ТС только учится

Comment: @nolka спасибо, что не прошли мимо:)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот "по-новому" написанный код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
<title>Соединение с БД MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'one', '12345', 'firstbd');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
    echo("Ошибка при загрузке набора символов utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
} else {
    echo("Текущий набор символов: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM firma")) {
    echo("<br>Select вернул %d строк.\n", mysqli_num_rows($result));

$myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  echo "<br>".$myrow['name'];
  echo "<br>".$myrow['surname'];

    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Сейчас уже не выходит никаких ошибок.

На скрине показано, что получается в результате.

[image]

Еще, в самом начале в meta у меня прописано windows-1251. Если меняю на utf-8, то вообще все выходит кракозябрами. Это как можно изменить?

Comment: Во-первых, если выводите в UTF-8, то и страницу должны отправлять в UTF-8.

Во-вторых, в какой кодировке сам файл страницы? UTF-8? Вряд ли, поменяйте кодировку в файле.

Не знаю на чем пишите, я использую [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). В нем достаточно просто выбрать в меню "Кодировки" -> "Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM"

Единственное, поскольку уже есть текст в другой кодировке, то лучше скопируйте все, преобразуйте в другую кодировку и вставьте скопированное - тогда с текстом проблем не будет.

Comment: Юху!:))
Кодировка у меня так и стояла Default Encoding: Юникод(UTF-8).
Но, по вашему совету, поставила галку на "Include Unicode Signature (BOM)".
В meta тоже поменяла кодировку на "UTF-8" -> И Ура!:)

Comment: @ВОРОН Спасибо за ответы! Пригодились:)

Comment: Я же сразу сказал где надо изменить, сделали бы сразу, не надо было бы еще раз спрашивать) Так же надо помечать ответ который помог, чтоб вопрос был "закрыт"

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла [эта инструкция](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php):

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Добавил последнюю строчку и в БД началась запись по-русски. Тоже ничего не помогало, в том числе замена кодировок в notepad++ и все что было рекомендовано выше. PHP-7.4.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]), чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается, от, например, [принятого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/220492/178576)