# Проблемы с кодировкой в БД

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Делаю небольшой проект, который использует сообщения из базы данных. Сами сценарии (на php) и страницы вывода информации из базы данных в кодировке utf-8. База данных также создана в кодировке utf-8.

Если прописываю в коде при добавлении и при выводе следующее:

```
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
 mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
```

то в базу записывается и отображается всё верно (кириллица отображается верно), кроме... некоторых смайликов (которые критичны для "заказчика", как оказалось). Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: 1. Выкиньте все функции `mysql_*`, они устарели и в php7 их уже нет. 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/220492/186083 (только вместо `utf8` используйте `utf8mb4`) 3. Базу переведите в 4хбайтовый UTF-8 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446474/186083

Answer (score 1):

> кроме некоторых смайликов

Это проблема ограниченности кодировки utf8 в mysql.
Чтобы ее обойти надо использовать кодировку `utfmb4`. Для этого ее надо задать для таблицы и для соединения.

Соответственно, таблицы создавать с кодировкой `utfmb4` вместо "utf-8" (которая на самом деле utf8), а после соединения писать **одну** строчку

```
mysql_set_charset('utfmb4');
```

И да, функций mysql_* больше не существует. Так что в своем небольшом проекте ты должен использовать PDO.

Comment: Дубликат ответов :p