# Знак вопроса вместо русских букв (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

Имеется локальный сервер на основе Endels, база данных MySQL `phonebook` и таблица `tblMain` в кодировке `utf8_general_ci`. Браузер принудительно установлен на такую же кодировку. В настройках Apache кодировка по умолчанию тоже назначена UTF8. Через phpmyadmin содержимое таблицы просматривается в нормальном виде - русские буквы отображаются корректно, однако, когда вывожу содержимое на сайт вместо русских букв знаки вопроса.
При проверке кодировки командой `$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);`я получаю результат `Текущая кодировка: latin1`
Откуда она берется не могу понять?!
Использую следующий код соединения:

```
<?php
// Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных
                    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'phonebook', 'phonebook')
                            or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
                    $charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);
                    echo "Текущая кодировка: $charset\n";
                    // echo 'Соединение успешно установлено';
                    mysql_select_db('phonebook') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

// Выполняем SQL-запрос
                    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tblMain';
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

// Выводим результаты в html
                    echo "<table class=table table_price table-condensed table-striped>\n";
                    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "\t<tbody><tr>\n";
                        foreach ($line as $col_value) {                            
                            echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
                        }
                        echo "\t</tr></tbody>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</table>\n";

// Освобождаем память от результата
                    mysql_free_result($result);

// Закрываем соединение
                    mysql_close($link);
                    ?>
```

Что за кодировка latin1 и как ее сменить на нужную?!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Установка кодировки в UTF-8 для текущего соединениния с MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37043/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-utf-8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-mysql)

Comment: *в кодировке utf8_general_ci* - это не charset, это collation.

Comment: [Как настроить правильно кодировку для MySQL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/220492/191482)

Answer (score 1):

1. Создайте в корне проекта файл .htaccess
2. Откройте файл и добавьте строчку

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Добавь `meta`-тег для кодировки в `head`:

```
meta charset='utf-8'
```