# LOAD DATA IN FILE mysql проблема с кодировкой

Tags: mysql, кодировка

есть файл вот с таким содержимым

```
0,Марк,0930880907
1,Андрей,0934535854
2,Дана,0502892517
```

сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
  telephone    INT(20) NOT NULL
)
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
ENGINE MyISAM;
```

занесенные данные в таблицу выглядят так

```
1   ÐœÐ°ÐºÐ°Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð° Ð  930880907
2   Ð”Ð°Ð½Ð°    502892517
```

команда на занесение

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/malinka/Стільниця/sit.my/MYSQ/test.txt'
IGNORE into table mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES terminated by '\n';
```

Что не так с кодировкой кто подскажет??

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в запрос: `... INTO TABLE mytable CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS ...`

Comment: Спасибо Деонис помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед тем как вставить данные установить кодировку соединения с сервером MySQL:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

Ещё проверьте кодировку файла `test.txt`, должно быть `utf8`.

Comment: так-же почитать можно вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/220416/Как-настроить-правильно-кодировку-для-mysql